# LogicApps with different data schema

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have the following HTTP Post with the following payload

{
"externalCode": "999",
"name": "PNNL - Winthrop, WA (Sundown L",
"description": "Winthrop",
"geozoneFlx": "PNL",
"status": "A",
"address1": "135 Sundown Lane",
"city": "WINTHROP",
"state": "WA",
"county": "OKANOGAN",
"country": "USA",
"zipCode": "98862-0339",
"timezone": "PST",
"startDate": "2016-01-27T00:00:00",
"endDate": "9999-12-31T00:00:00"
},

HOWEVER, some data message come into the Logic App looking like this with no "State" "name" in the data like this

"externalCode": "999",
"name": "PNNL - Winthrop, WA (Sundown L",
"description": "Winthrop",
"geozoneFlx": "PNL",
"status": "A",
"address1": "135 Sundown Lane",
"city": "WINTHROP",
"county": "OKANOGAN",
"country": "USA",
"zipCode": "98862-0339",
"timezone": "PST",
"startDate": "2016-01-27T00:00:00",
"endDate": "9999-12-31T00:00:00"
},

I have to say if the data message comes in without the State json Name like above, kick it out. How do I filter for a missing json field such as "State" in the above??

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can judge whether the length of the value of the `state` field is greater than 0, if it is greater than 0, execute your original logic, if the length of the value is 0, you don't need to do anything. The design of the logic app is as follows:

[image]

If the request body of your http request is a json array, you can use the `for each` loop to process.

The expression for obtaining the length of the state field in condition is as follows:

```
length(coalesce(body('Parse_JSON')?['state'], ''))
```

For the usage of [coalesce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#coalesce) and [length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#length), you can refer to the official documentation